# How can I transform a string of comma and brackets seperated list into another string?

Tags: jquery, arrays, join, split

I try to transform my string (that is a list of values) into another string.
I have problems, because I do not really know how to do it. This is what I achieved until now:

```js
var input = "cat(13),dog(12),bird(14)";
var array = input.split(',');
   
var result = [];

$(array).each(function( g, h ) {
    result.push("("+h.split(")").join('id:-name:-<br>'));
});

$(document.body).append(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The result I actually would need is:

```
id:13-name:cat-
id:12-name:dog-
id:14-name:bird-
```

But I am stuck...

Comment: you can use `match` function to extract needed part from each of your string `match(/[a-zA-Z]+/)` for letter and match(/\d+/) for number part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no regex expert, but this code seems to work, using the `match()` function:

```js
var input = "cat(13),dog(12),bird(14)";
var array = input.split(',');
   
var result = [];

$(array).each(function( g, h ) {
  result.push(
    'id:' +
    h.match(/\d+/) + /* matches the numbers */
    '-name:' +
    h.match(/[a-z]+/i) + /* matches the text */
    '-<br />'
    );
});

$(document.body).append(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Alternative based on comment

```js
var input = "c4t(13a),d0gg13(1ab2),bird(14)";
var array = input.split(',');
   
var result = [];

$(array).each(function( g, h ) {
  var split = h.split('(');
  result.push(
    'id:' +
    split[0] + /* matches the numbers */
    '-name:' +
    split[1].slice(0,-1) + /* matches the text */
    '-<br />'
    );
});

$(document.body).append(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Alterative with regex

```js
var input = "c4t(13a),d0gg13(1ab2),bird(14)";
var array = input.split(',');
   
var result = [];

$(array).each(function( g, h ) {
  result.push(h.replace(/(\w+)\((\w+)\)/, 'id:$1-name:$2-<br />'));
});

$(document.body).append(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem is, that my names sometimes contain numbers and the numbers contains letters. So what I need is to get the values inside the brackets and the values before the brackets

Comment: And another (even better ;) ) solution with a working regex.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the code you need without jQuery for you.

```js
var input = "cat(13),dog(12),bird(14)";
var array = input.split(',');
   
var result = [];

// other way of looping an array
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    // this way you replace the entry with another string with inserted parameters;
    // if you need more info on how what works you can ask me or search for "regex" and "js string replace"
    result.push(array[i].replace(/(\w+)\((\d+)\)/,function(full,p1,p2){return "id:"+p2+"-name:"+p1+"-";}));
};
console.log(result);

document.body.innerHTML += result;
```